# JS: reload whole page or go to another page without refresh specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a mp3 player on my website and this mp3 player is fixed in my website

and if I reload my page or go to another page of my website

it can still here and not be refreshed.
for example:

Page 1.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id ="nav">2222222222222</div>
<div id ="mp3">11111111111</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Page 2:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id ="nav">2222222222222</div>
<div id ="main">11111111111</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

when I try to fresh page 1,and music has stared to play,the id="mp3" player will not be refreshed,

when I go to the Page 2,the id="mp3" div still work.so how can I achieve it?

Comment: When you say `refresh page`, did you mean click the refresh button in the browser?

Comment: What you are looking for is ' Multiple html pages in one page i suppose' .you can google it. However have you thought of using it as seperate components using react . You can sperate the components . In your case you can keep one component mp3 that can be static i.e available to all the pages . And you can make another component dynamic, i.e serve different pages.